# Hamming distance in ancient Microsoft DBMS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, hamming-distance, sql-server-7

## The Problem

I want to find image duplicates and similar images in MS SQL Server 7.

#### Edit

I got it running using sql cursors - it's slow but it works, thanks again for the comment. See my answer for the solution I came up with.

### Specifically ...

I have a database containing image paths and the *fingerprints* of the associated images computed with the help of [this dhash algorithm](http://www.hackerfactor.com/blog/index.php?/archives/529-Kind-of-Like-That.html). I'm using a variation where I'm storing 128 bits per image (horizontal and vertical gradient) in a `BINARY(16)` column.

What I want to be able to do is something in the lines of:

```sql
DECLARE @id INT
SET @id = ...

DECLARE @given_hash BINARY(16)
SET @given_hash = ...

SELECT TOP 10 file_path,hash,
    (hamming_distance(hash, @given_hash)) AS distance
FROM my_table
WHERE distance <= 20
ORDER BY distance ASC
```

### What is working?

It is trivial to obtain exact duplicates - just use a `WHERE hash = @hash_to_compare` and that's it.

### What's not working?

However, I want to be able to use a similarity measure ([Hamming Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance)) to account for small manipulations/defects/compression artifacts etc. 
I've come up with a stored procedure implementing the distance measure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE hamming_distance128
    @hash BINARY(16),
    @supplied BINARY(16)
AS
    DECLARE @i INT, @j INT
    SET @i = 1
    SET @j = 1

    DECLARE @count INT
    SET @count = 0

    DECLARE @byte TINYINT

    DECLARE @length TINYINT
    SET @length = 16

    WHILE @i <= @length
    BEGIN
        SET @j = 1
        SET @byte = CAST((ASCII(SUBSTRING(@hash,@i,1)) ^ ASCII(SUBSTRING(@supplied,@i,1))) AS TINYINT)

        WHILE @j < 256
        BEGIN
            SET @count = @count + (CASE (@byte & @j) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
            SET @j = @j * 2
        END

        SET @i = @i + 1
    END

    SELECT @count
GO
```

Unfortunately the DBMS (SQL Server 7 - it's impossible to upgrade/change this) won't let me use it to compute distances within a query and this piece of j*nk doesn't support user defined functions. Sure enough I didn't find anything like MySQL's `BIT_COUNT` that would make this a no brainer for T-SQL.

Is there hope of getting this to work in T-SQL on SQL Server 7?

Help very much appreciated!

Comment: Most likely you'll have to loop through the table and apply a function in your favorite programming language.  What does "won't let me" mean?

Comment: I have a feeling that you're right but I would appreciate not having to resort to writing a custom SQL Server dll for this ... I have a feeling it's not supported anyways. "won't let me" just means that I can not use that stored procedure to compute the column values within the query ... I don't know if it's generally possible or not, it just refuses to do it :-)

Comment: How about using a temp table and a cursor to populate it? You could wrap that in another stored proc and return the temp table as its result.

Comment: @Tomalak: thanks for the advise, I'm not an SQL pro but I got it working after reading about sql cursors - every source strongly suggests not to use them but right now I don't see another way. For the solution see my update

Comment: @vanhelgen The sources are right in terms of "solutions including cursors are much slower than they could be, due to the sequential nature of cursors". However, cursors exist for a reason. They can solve problems queries can't. And this, on SQL Server 7.0, is such a problem. There is nothing wrong with a cursor here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it running using SQL cursors and a temporary table. Thanks again @Tomalak

I provide my implementation for future reference, hope this is useful to anyone

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE hamming_distance128
    @hash BINARY(16),
    @supplied BINARY(16),
    @distance TINYINT OUTPUT
AS
    DECLARE @i INT, @j INT
    SET @i = 1
    SET @j = 1

    DECLARE @count TINYINT
    SET @count = 0

    DECLARE @byte TINYINT

    DECLARE @length TINYINT
    SET @length = 16

    WHILE @i <= @length
    BEGIN
        SET @j = 1
        SET @byte = CAST((ASCII(SUBSTRING(@hash,@i,1)) ^ ASCII(SUBSTRING(@supplied,@i,1))) AS TINYINT)

        WHILE @j < 256
        BEGIN
            SET @count = @count + (CASE (@byte & @j) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
            SET @j = @j * 2
        END

        SET @i = @i + 1
    END

    SET @distance = @count
GO


DECLARE @min_similarity FLOAT
SET @min_similarity = 0.85 -- | 85%

DECLARE @supplied_hash BINARY(16)
SET @supplied_hash = 0x392929295B4B13371B0301272D2B2509

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#distances') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN DROP TABLE #distances END

CREATE TABLE #distances
(id INT NOT NULL,
 similarity FLOAT NOT NULL)

DECLARE
    @tmp_id INT,
    @dhash BINARY(16),
    @distance TINYINT,
    @similarity FLOAT

DECLARE rowCursor CURSOR
LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY
FOR
    SELECT id,dhash_value
    FROM hashes
    OPEN rowCursor
        FETCH NEXT FROM rowCursor
        INTO @tmp_id,@dhash

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            EXECUTE hamming_distance128 @dhash, @supplied_hash, @distance OUTPUT

            IF @distance < 128
            BEGIN
                SET @similarity = CAST(128 - @distance AS FLOAT) / 128.0

                IF @similarity >= @min_similarity
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO #distances (id,similarity)
                    VALUES (@tmp_id,@similarity)
                END
            END

            FETCH NEXT FROM rowCursor
            INTO @tmp_id,@dhash
        END
    CLOSE rowCursor
DEALLOCATE rowCursor

SELECT hashes.id,#distances.similarity
FROM #distances
    INNER JOIN hashes
    ON hashes.id = #distances.id
ORDER BY #distances.similarity DESC

DROP TABLE #distances
```

Comment: Moved my solution to the answer - it really makes more sense

Comment: I think I just spotted a bug. You call `FETCH NEXT` twice at the start, thus disregarding the first row. You ought to call `FETCH NEXT FROM rowCursor INTO @tmp_id, @dhash` once before the loop starts and then repeatedly at the end of each iteration.

Comment: You're welcome. I think the rest of the code looks fine.